# I can't find my MySQL folder in %ProgramData%

Tags: mysql, import, text-files

First of all, I just want to say that I'm new to SQL, so forgive me if I'm being ignorant or something.

I'm working on this project and I need to import data from a text file. My first thought was to use this command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE names;
```

Where my text file is **test** and my table is **names**.

However, I got this error message:

```
Error Code: 2. File '\tmp\teste.txt' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
```

I tried to save this file in the tmp folder but I still got this same error. I was told that maybe the problem is in my.ini (something about the --secure-file-priv) but I just can't find my MySQL folder in **C:\ProgramData**. Apparently, that is where my.ini is supposed to be. So, any ideas of what is going on?

By the way, I'm not confusing **C:\Program Files** and **C:\ProgramData**

P.S: I use Windows 10 and MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE.

Comment: I believe ProgramData is a hidden folder. Can you manually check if it is there?

Comment: If you're on Windows, then how did you manage to create a file named `/tmp/test.txt`? That is not a Windows file path. Only you can tell us where you _really_ put the file — now tell MySQL, too, in your `LOAD DATA` statement!

Answer (score 1):

Alright pals, the problem is solved. I honestly don't know how I managed to find the problem but I did and as expected, it was a silly one. The correct statement would be:

```
load data infile 'c:\\wamp\\tmp\\test.txt' into table names;
```

I got confused with all that slashes thing, because for directories you use \ or /. So my mistake was doing this:

```
load data infile 'c:\wamp\tmp\test.txt' into table names;
```

Using only one backslash instead of two, which is wrong. Finally, I just needed to put my text file in the tmp folder and use the appropriate backslashes (no need for LOCAL). Thanks for the help!